# std::thread Parameter type mismatch: Expression must be rvalue

Tags: clion

I have  CLion 1.2  on Mint Maya with installed gcc5. Default gcc is 4.6. (/usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.6)
Compiler set through CMakeLists and Settings
[toolchain settings] https://www.dropbox.com/s/se5nxfdki7zdkhm/screen_settings_toolchain.png
[sample] https://www.dropbox.com/s/ss7r6kss64k00ez/screen.png

Editor say:  Parameter type mismatch: Expression must be rvalue on  std::thread t1(f1) but I can build and run this sample

What is wrong?

Sample:

```
void f1(){
cout<<"hi"<<endl;
}
int main() {
cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
std::thread t1(f1);//Parameter type mismatch: Expression must be rvalue
t1.join();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [cmake settings]: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o85bpm0b2dsh183/screen_settings_cmake.png

Answer (score 6):

I believe it's a parser [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5004) of clion

### UPDATE

> **Affected versions:** CLion 1.2
>
> **Fix versions:** CLion 2016.1